# Fitting one set of data with two function

Tags: functions, fitting

I have a set of data (42 points):

```
{{1.1*10^6, 1/21}, {600., 3/7}, {80., 5/7}, {100., 29/42}, {600., 3/
  7}, {600., 3/7}, {70., 31/42}, {500., 19/42}, {25., 37/42}, {25., 
  37/42}, {300., 4/7}, {25., 37/42}, {15000., 5/42}, {150., 2/
  3}, {1400., 13/42}, {10., 1}, {60., 16/21}, {200., 13/21}, {10000., 
  4/21}, {10000., 4/21}, {1000., 5/14}, {50., 17/21}, {1500., 2/
  7}, {200., 13/21}, {300., 4/7}, {5000., 3/14}, {10., 1}, {80000., 1/
  14}, {20., 13/14}, {1575., 11/42}, {400., 1/2}, {1000., 5/
  14}, {9.1671*10^6, 1/42}, {60000., 2/21}, {20., 13/14}, {50., 17/
  21}, {400., 1/2}, {150., 2/3}, {10., 1}, {10000., 4/21}, {350., 11/
  21}, {2200., 5/21}}
```

that's look like (Log-Log plot):

[image]
where x-coordinate represent area (of forest fire, in m^2), and y-coordinate represent number of fires that are equal or greater than value on x-coordinate, divided by total numbers of fire (cumulative distribution).

"First part" of data fits very good with so-called "stretched exponential":

(y=exp -(x/A)^beta),

where *A* and *beta* are constants that I must find.

"Second part" of data fits better to Power law

(y=C*x^(-alpha)),

where *C* and *alpha* are also constants that I must find.

My question is: how to make Mathematica to find best fit for this data and for BOTH function at the same time? I want to get X*-value that is "border" between this two function, all constants that are present in functions and curve that is smooth but consist of two part: left part ("before" X*) should be a part of stretched exponential (curve in this graph) and right part ("after" X*) should be plot of Power law (straight line in LogLogPlot).

How to do all of that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could try `Piecewise`.

Comment: It is not an unreasonable question, but I am not sure it is a *Mathematica* question...

Comment: I have tried a lot of "by hand" methods but I must, to avoid human mistake, left to Mathematica to find "border value" (X*).

Comment: To Oleksandr R.: I think it is Mathematica question because in forest fire (and mathematical - physicas similar problems, like spread of oil on sea for example), if fire behavior is like stretched exponential (where is "A" value, witch represent area) then fire is "under control" until area of that size. If it is similar to Power law, who have no scale, than small fire behavior is similar to big one (and vice versa) and fire behavior is not independent of human activities, it depends only on "outside" factors like (big) rain or natural border (like water, big slope bold rock ect.)

Comment: Sory, in last post "is not independent" should be "is independent"

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point. It is not a *Mathematica* question because the only thing it has to do with *Mathematica* rather than, say, MATLAB or Origin, is that you coincidentally happen to be using *Mathematica*. I am sure you are correct about the physical model of forest fires but this has nothing to do with the software you are using. In my opinion you would get a more useful answer if you were to ask this at [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). It is just a suggestion.

Comment: I agree with @OleksandrR.in that the CrossValidated site is a more appropriate place to ask your question.  I do wonder if your data needs some fixing.  There are several points that have the same exact values.  For instance there are 3 10's, 2 20's, 3 25's, 2 50's, 2 150's, etc.  There are only 26 unique data points.

Comment: To Jim Baldwin: there are more fires with (approximately) same burned area, that is reason why doubles are present

Comment: To Oleksandr R., Jim Baldwin and all other: I apologize if I miss site with question. In general, I would love to know how to fit data with two function without doing it "by hand", with Mathematica. Sorry if I interrupt concept of this site. And thanks for suggestion!

Comment: If you do post to CrossValidated, I suggest that you include the raw frequency counts for each fire size class.  Typically, raw counts for each fire size class are used to fit a probability distribution from which a cumulative distribution is determined rather than starting with a cumulative distribution based on relative frequencies.  (For starters, all of the observations of a cumulative distribution are correlated with each other violating the usual assumptions of independence.)

Comment: To Jim Baldwin: I find your last suggestion very interesting and I would like to ask you more about that; I just don't know is it allowed to continue with discussion on this post?

Answer (score 4):

**see comment below by OleskandrR**

If he posts I will up vote.
**Original post**

This is not ideal (and done with little time) but may motivate better answers. Note this manually (visually tries to minimize the discontinuity at "breakpoint") using `Manipulate`. The `NonlinearModelFit` treats the breakpoint as fixed so you can play and chose better way. I look forward to better ways but am too time poor to think about.

Set up:

```
data = {{1.1*10^6, 1/21}, {600., 3/7}, {80., 5/7}, {100., 
    29/42}, {600., 3/7}, {600., 3/7}, {70., 31/42}, {500., 
    19/42}, {25., 37/42}, {25., 37/42}, {300., 4/7}, {25., 
    37/42}, {15000., 5/42}, {150., 2/3}, {1400., 13/42}, {10., 
    1}, {60., 16/21}, {200., 13/21}, {10000., 4/21}, {10000., 
    4/21}, {1000., 5/14}, {50., 17/21}, {1500., 2/7}, {200., 
    13/21}, {300., 4/7}, {5000., 3/14}, {10., 1}, {80000., 
    1/14}, {20., 13/14}, {1575., 11/42}, {400., 1/2}, {1000., 
    5/14}, {9.1671*10^6, 1/42}, {60000., 2/21}, {20., 13/14}, {50., 
    17/21}, {400., 1/2}, {150., 2/3}, {10., 1}, {10000., 4/21}, {350.,
     11/21}, {2200., 5/21}};
```

Putative model function:

```
f[x_, a_, b_, c_, d_, g_] := 
 Boole[x < d] Exp[-(x/a)^b] + (1 - Boole[x < d]) c x^(-g)
```

`NonlinearModelFit` with startiing values from playing with `Manipulate`:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  f[x, a, b, c, d, 
   g], {{a, 836}, {b, 0.41}, {c, 3.87}, {d, 1980}, {g, 0.36}}, x]
```

Note:

`nlm["AdjustedRSquared"]` yields: 0.996793

`nlm["ParameterTable"]`:

[image]

Visualizing:

```
Show[
 ListLogLogPlot[data], 
 LogLogPlot[nlm2[x], {x, 10, 10000000}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]]
```

`Normal@nlm`:

```
(2.28415 (1 - Boole[x < 1980.]))/x^0.282831 + 
 E^(-0.0243126 x^0.551201) Boole[x < 1980.]
```

Good luck...note again this just uses the cut point from `Manipulate` look forward to better answers

[image]

Comment: It is probably better to enforce continuity as a constraint and let `NonlinearModelFit` find the value of `d` appropriately to that. But the big problem with this model is that it is overdetermined and so `d` is not really treated as a parameter. `nlm=NonlinearModelFit[data,{f[x,a,b,c,d,g],Exp[-(d/a)^b]==c d^(-g)&&a>1&&b>0&&c>0&&d>1},{{a,500},{b,1},{c,3},{d,200},{g,0.3}},
x,Method->{NMinimize,Method->"NelderMead"}]` gives a different result, which looks better to my eye, although I would still have zero confidence that it is correct.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yes I agree with constraint and also 'zero confidence'...just thought might illustrate a start...without knowing what data is and why model plausible or what aim is...just play...thank you for your comment as I always learn...

Comment: I want to note that my comment was not intended as a criticism of your answer, which I think shows basically the right approach. I just meant to point out that there are difficulties in applying the approach straightforwardly because of the mathematical structure of the model.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I appreciated and agreed with your comment and just wanted to direct the answer to your comment which I think gets closer to the aim...very time poor at present...

Comment: Thanks for both of you for all comments and suggestions. I was hoping that there is some specific (and "simply" :) order fort his type of a problem. I've tried to find a solution on many web pages; on this also, I will search further... And thanks for all future suggestions!